# J2ME - encryption and decryption of mp3 files

Tags: java, java-me, encryption, bouncycastle

I am creating an J2ME application - MP3 player to play the encrypted MP3 files.For this I need some API or logic to encrypt the Mp3 file and to decrypt the same in J2ME. If any one knows how to do encryption and decryption in J2ME please share your thoughts and procedure here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean *encrypted* or *encoded*?  They have very different meanings in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/